# Amazon Product Uploads in Inventory not working...?

Tags: amazon-product-api

I am using a tab separated file to upload some products to inventory.

Am I am getting the errors bellow:

```
original-record-number sku error-code error-type error-message
10983436    8105    Error   The data you provided for an attribute does not match the list of valid values.  Please select a valid value from the Data Definitions and resubmit.
10983436    8105    Error   The data you provided for an attribute does not match the list of valid values.  Please select a valid value from the Data Definitions and resubmit.
```

My file content is this:

```
1   10983436    8560    Error   SKU 10983436, Missing Attributes product_type. SKU 10983436 does not match any ASIN. Creation of a new ASIN requires the following missing attributes: product_type. Feed ID: 0. For details, see http://sellercentral.amazon.co.uk/gp/errorcode/200692370
sku product-id  product-id-type price   item-condition  quantity    add-delete  will-ship-internationally   expedited-shipping  item-note
10983436    471954318111    4   14.8700 11  10  a   3   3   Brand new factory sealed item.
```

I don't understand what's the problem.

Can someone please help?

Answer (score 0):

I was having this problem and it turned out to be nothing whatsoever to do with the data at all but it was the columns.  The Amazon uploader had changed and no longer was accepting the columns I was providing.  I removed them and the message went away. You may be spelling a column incorrectly also which would create the same type of error. 
Danel